# Dotnetcore: how to get httpClient from a service reference?

Tags: .net-core, service-reference

I think I need to figure out how to get the httpclient from a service reference.

I've been connecting to a web service that returns a certificate error.  I want to bypass that error, and in dotnet framework, that's simple.  However, in core, I'm told I have to get the httpClient and add a custom handler to it.  That's fine, but when I have is a service reference object to the web service, and I can't figure out how to get an httpClient from that.

First, I added a service reference to a web service (not one I control).

next,

BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

```
    httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

    httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

    httpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;

        SRI_CAP_AlertCollector.AlertCollectorServicePortClient client = new SRI_CAP_AlertCollector.AlertCollectorServicePortClient(httpBinding, endpoint);
```

but when I call one of the service methods (asynchronously), I get an error because of the certificate.
Since this is a proof-of-concept, I want to bypass the certificate error.

In DotNetCore, doing so is done differently than with dotnet framework.  So I was trying to figure out how to get the httpClientHandler from the service reference so that I can add a ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback

Comment: Hey Les, there isn't quite enough information to go off of here. Could you add some code and explain what problem you are trying to solve in the larger context of your application?

Comment: see the added verbiage above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you work with .net core I would suggest that you use HttpClientFactory. Optimally you can register a named client factory in DI container like below.

```
services.AddHttpClient("named_client")
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
                {
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

                //Get certificate

                X509Certificate2 cert = null;
                //Load your certificate                

                if (cert == null) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"No certificate found");

                handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
                handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;

                return handler;
            });
```

On the code above `HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator` wraps the callback function that returns `true`.
When you resolve the `httpfactory` in the class, and you create a new client, you should do it like

```
public class ClassResponsibleForHttpCalls
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public ClassResponsibleForHttpCalls(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
    public async Task Get(int id)
    {
        requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "";
        using var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("named_client");

        //Use your client...
    }
}
```

Use as a parameter the very same name client that you set before.

Comment: what do I put for "named_client"
what name will I look for in my service reference?

Comment: it's not working.  still getting the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority error.

Comment: I updated my answer. "named_client" is just a name. You should use the same name when you create a client from the factory. Check my updated answer

Comment: I guess I don't know how to make that work using the scaffolded service reference.